# Rails as_json issue - How to include nested objects efficiently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running into an issue where I'm working with the as_json method, and how to efficiently return the object in JSON *AND* it's belongs_to object as JSON as well, where the belongs_to object has its own belongs_to object.  Code would probably explain it better.

The Not-Working Way

**Alert class**

```
class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :message
    # for json rendering
    def as_json(options={})
        super(:include => :message)
    end
end
```

**Message class**

```
 def as_json(options={})
    super( methods: [:timestamp, :num_photos, :first_photo_url, :tag_names],
           include: { camera: { only: [:id, :name] },
                      position: { only: [:id, :name, :address, :default_threat_level ]},
                      images: { only: [:id, :photo_url, :is_hidden]} })
  end
```

The problem with this first set up is that when I have an Alert object and call

```
alert.as_json()
```

I get all the attributes from Alert and all the attributes from Message, but none of the other attributes from Message that I want, like Camera, Position, etc.

Here's the "It's Working, But Probably Not Proper Design Way"

**Alert Class**

```
class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :message

    # for json rendering
    def as_json(options={})
        super().merge(:message => message.as_json)
    end
end
```

**Messages Class**

```
  # for json rendering
  def as_json(options={})
    super( methods: [:timestamp, :num_photos, :first_photo_url, :tag_names])
          .merge(:camera => camera.as_json)
          .merge(:position => position.as_json)
          .merge(:images => images.as_json)
  end
```

In this 2nd setup, I get all of Messages's nested attributes like I want.

My question, am I missing some Rails Convention to do this properly?  It seems like there would/should be an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Rails are you using? This is a known bug in older versions of Rails, supposedly fixed with [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2200). Your syntax looks right to me, so perhaps this is your problem?

As an aside, you may also want to checkout the new [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers) from Jose Valim (Rails core member). It may at least enable you to work around your issue in a more elegant manner.

Comment: Well it looks like they fixed it with the pull request, but never pulled it into a version.  Thanks for the link, it cleared up a few issues.

Comment: For the record, what I got from that PR is: 1) try to use a specific gem for the json api (I favor Active Model Serializers) 2) If you don't want/ can't do that, override `serialized_hash` instead of `as_json` in all your models. Just replace `as_json` by `serialized_hash`. Your models will correctly render included dependencies.

Comment: thanks kikito, minor correction, it's `serializable_hash`

Answer (score 7):

The best answer for me was using `serializable_hash`. @kikito touched on this in his comment, but there was a typo that prevented it from working. It's not `serialized_hash`, it's `serializable_hash`.

Literally just find + replace `as_json` with `serializable_hash` and this bug goes away. (It's still not fixed in today's Rails 4.0.2). You also get the benefit of having an easier time implementing an XML API later (some people still use those!).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to take a look at RABL (stands for Ruby API Builder Language) gem ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl), [github](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/)). It offers you a DSL for defining the structure of your JSON (and also XML) response in templates (like Haml or CoffeeScript does). It also supports partials.